# ASP.NET User not showing all Active Directory Groups

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, active-directory

I am trying to use windows authentication and active directory groups to manage the security within an application.  The problem I am running into is that in the code behind of a page I am trying to verify is a user hitting the ASP.NET website is a member of a specific AD group and then showing/hiding a few items based on that.  The issue I am running into is that I cannot seem to get all the groups that the user is a member of in order to test.  I have included the code below that I am using to list all the groups the user belongs to.  This code does return a number of groups, however it is not returning all the groups.  I have verified in the AD controller that all the groups appear to be set the same.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Function GetCurrentGroups() As ArrayList
    Dim groups As New ArrayList()
    For Each group As System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference In System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups
        groups.Add(group.Translate(GetType(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString())
    Next

    groups.Sort()

    Return groups
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - you're most likely only seeing the **direct** group memberships of your user.

Any *nested* membership - `User` being member of `GroupA` which in turn is member of `GroupB` - are typically not shown - so in this case, you would see `GroupA` but not `GroupB`.

If you really need this information, you'd have to interrogate Active Directory directly (using something like the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) namespace - [great MSDN article about using it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)).

The `S.DS.AM` namespace contains among other things a class `UserPrincipal` representing a user in AD, and this class has a method called `.GetAuthorizationGroups()` which **will** return **all** groups a user is member of - including nested groups.

Comment: From the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357862.aspx) it looks like .GetGroups() only returns direct groups, but GetAuthorizationGroups() will return nested groups (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is this. 
Assume that 
the AD group is **G** and is in the domain **A**
the User **U** in domain **B** is a member of **G**  (this is possible in universal groups)
If **A** trusts **B** but NOT vice versa, calling **G.GetMembers** will return the user. However, if you call **U.GetGroups** will return not return AD group in domain **A**.